# How to prevent the rubber peg on a flip-flop from popping out

Tags: clothing, shoes

I have a pair of cheap, but comfortable flip flops. I like them, but the rubber peg between the big toe and the second toe always comes out. I don't want to have to get new flip-flops. I've tried using glue, but that did not turn out well. **How can I prevent the rubber peg on my flip-flops from popping out?**

[image: Broken flip-flop]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best hack for this is to use a bread clip. Push the peg back through the hole. Now put the bread clip around the broken peg. You don't have to, but you can glue it using super glue for more strength.

[image: Bread clips fix flip-flops]

If you don't have a bread tab or you want the extra strength, but you don't have super glue, you can just use hair pin or a paper clip. You'll have to put a hole in the peg. You can do this by actually drilling a hole, but you can also poke something sharp through like a knife. Now you put just put the hair pin or paper clip in the hole and you're good to go.

[image: alternative solution]

---

Sources: [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Repair-Flip-Flops), [LifeH4cks](http://lifeh4cks.com/save-flip-flops-spilt-holes/)